# Mistaken shehakol - correct it?

Tags: blessing, mistakes

If I make a *shehakol* bracha and then discover that the correct bracha for the food I am eating is, say, *mezonot*, should I now make a new *mezonot* bracha on the remainder of the food? Or does the initial *shehakol* cover it?

Comment: You should not recite a new *b'racha* (unless you remember *toch k'dei dibbur*); the initial *shehakol* covers it (based on the Mishna on [B'rachos 40a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=77&size=2); Shulchan Aruch OC 206:1).

Comment: Thanks, Fred, that's what I thought. Why don't you put your comment into an answer?

Comment: For a good 15 seconds I read the first word in the title as מסתכן

Comment: @Fred I am also curious why that is not considered an answer...

Comment: @andrewmh20 and Michael Sandler - I didn't originally post it as an answer because I was in a hurry and would've preferred if someone posted a more thorough answer with every detail cited, but I've now posted it as an answer (mostly as is).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not recite a new blessing; the initial *shehakol* covers it (based on the Mishna on [B'rachos 40a](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=77&size=2); Shulchan Aruch OC 206:1). If you recall immediately that you concluded the blessing incorrectly, you may correct the conclusion of the blessing *toch k'dei dibbur* (within approximately 2 seconds).