“Redundant” morning blessing?

Some poskim say that if you mistakenly say Zokef Kfufim before Matir
Asurim, one should not go back and say Matir Asurim.[3

https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchot_HaShachar#Order_of_Brachot
From my understanding, the reason is because one bracha is included within the other so if you say the latter one first you have already given thanks to the former and therefore cannot say another bracha for something you have already said thanks for.
My question is, wouldn’t this be a ברכה שאינה צריכה, I.e a redundant, un-needed blessing and therefore we should not be saying the former bracha at all? Why is it not considered bracha she’eino tzricha?

Same logic applies to before blessings for food, we can just say shehakol

@RabbiKaii You don't skip mezonos if you said shehakol first.

@shmosel https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/25650/31534. You shouldn't necessarily skip anything if you say shehakol first, but I didn't mean to discuss lemaaseh

Maybe a better comparison is the requirement to make בורא עשבי בשמים and the like before the more inclusive בורא מיני בשמים.

It's perfectly valid to ask according to this opinion, and the answer below is reasonable, but know that most siddurim from before the shulchan aruch first suggested this opinion did indeed have zokef kefufim before mattir asurim.

The Ta"z (Orach Chaim 212 S"K 3) says that that rule only applies to making the same Berachah twice, not to two different Berachot, like by Ikar and Tafel.

The Taz on Shulchan Aruch O"C 46:5 explains that the blessings were originally instituted to be said as one goes through the morning motions, i.e. Matir Asurim upon sitting up and stretching, and Zokef Kfufim upon standing upright. When each blessing is said in its proper context, they're not redundant, because they're each said at a distinct stage. But if someone forgot to say Matir Asurim, it would become redundant at the Zokef Kfufim stage and they would have to skip it.
Nowadays, we say them all together, preserving the ones that are theoretically redundant so as not to deviate from the way it was instituted by the sages. But if one accidentally said Zokef Kfufim first, it would be like one who missed the Matir Asurim blessing in its proper stage, making it now fully redundant.

Maybe it is also necessary to stretch before streightening? For example, medical research showed that to avoid getting heart condition, one needs to wait about 12 seconds before getting up - the time equivalent to saying Modeh ani.

Thank you, but I still don’t understand with these specific brachot, since one can cover the other,why the need to split them up? Just say one bracha after you stretch and stand up…because if not why don’t we split it up even further and when we move our arm say a bracha , when we move our knee say another bracha etc none of the other brachot can cover one another but here they can so even though it’s seperate actions combine it to one, because again if not then why can’t I split up another of the other brachas further and say more brachot?

I'm sure they could have bundled the entire set of blessings into one long one (same for prayer etc.), but obviously they felt certain things deserved to be singled out. If you want to get into why, that should probably be a separate question.
